# gulp-rev creates a directory inside the destination directory

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rev

First of all, I would like to say that Gulp (for me) is creating more problems instead of solving them.

I wrote a gulpfile that concat some CSS files and put them inside a directory. The code for this task is the following:

```
var config = {
    mainDir: 'app/assets'
};

config.stylesFiles = [
    'bower_resources/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css',
    'bower_resources/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css',
    'css/app.css'
];

....

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(config.stylesFiles, { cwd: config.mainDir })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('theme.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../build/css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'))
        .on('end', function() { gutil.log('Styles copied') });
});
```

It is very simple and works perfectly.

But, I would like to version this generated file. So I wrote a specific task to do it:

```
....

config.manifestFolder = process.cwd() + '/public/build';

gulp.task('versionCSS', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(['css/theme.css'], { cwd: 'public' })
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/css'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest( 
            {
                base: config.manifestFolder, 
                cwd: config.manifestFolder, 
                merge: true 
            } 
         ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.manifestFolder))
        .on('end', function() { gutil.log('CSS files versioned') });
});
```

The problem is: when Gulp is going to run this task, it creates a folder inside the destination folder.

After running Gulp, I get this structure:

```
- public
  - build
    - css (destination folder for the versioned file)
      - css (folder created by Gulp)
        - versioned file that should be in the parent folder
  - css
    - concatenated file without version
```

I really don't know what to do anymore. I've already set the `cwd` and `base` options for the `dest` and `src` functions, changed the destinations, synchronized the tasks, etc. Nothing solves this stupid behavior.

Comment: So just leave the `css` out of your destination path: `.pipe(gulp.dest('public/build'))`

Comment: @SvenSchoenung It doesn't work. Now the file is not saved.